Problem with reactivity of pinia getters in imported npm package (vue 2.7)

Vue 2.7.14 (options api)
Pinia 2.1.7

I have ChildApp where in "standalone" mode I normally use pinia after initializing it in main.js and everything works.

Below is my store initialization. I need to pass store id as param coz I can have X number of stores.

Till now everything works fine.
What i need to do is to export some components of ChildApp (which are using pinia store) to the ParentApp. I'm doing it by adding export in index.js file
export { default as Form } from "./components/Form/Form";

In the ParentApp I'm also initializing pinia in main.js the same way as in ChildApp. I have other stores in ParentApp unrelated to this topic so I know everything with pinia init is ok.
I import one example component from ChildApp npm package as below.

Strangely enough, I had to do 2 things to make everything work "somehow":

Make 2nd initialization of pinia in ParentApp (as mentioned I do it in main.js) but with imported Form component.

import { Form } from "@form-library/dist/form.esm.js";
import { createPinia, PiniaVuePlugin } from "pinia";

import Vue from "vue";
Vue.use(PiniaVuePlugin);
const pinia = createPinia();
new Vue({ pinia, render: (h) => h(qmsCreatorFormAdd) });


In ChildApp I needed to add pinia initialization object (this.$pinia) everywhere where I'm using store


Everything would be good but the problem is with the getters of pinia store. They don't work in ParentApp when I initialize everything like this. In standalone mode of ChildApp all works but in imported npm package not. What is interesing is that I can normally use actions and use store $state instead of getters and then reactivity is handled properly.
Is there a way to use this getters in ParentApp. Am I'm doing something wrong?
I used 2nd pinia instance initialization in component where I import npm package and using this.$pinia when importing store in ChildApp components
